# Response from POST request is not returning an object, using AXIOS library with Front-End React and Sanic as Back-End framework

Tags: reactjs, axios, request, response, sanic

im just starting a simple login project. The requests are happening normally, but when i send a post request expecting to return an error object from AXIOS lib it doesnt return anything. When it succeeds it works normally but i would like to recieve and handle the error in front-end. At Insomnia it works perfectly, but at development environment it doesnt. Any ideas how to solve it ?

**Code at Front-End :**

**path/api.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";

    export const request = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8800",
        timeout: 1000
    })
```

**path/Home.jsx**

```
const dataHandlerPost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await request.post("/users", JSON.stringify(jsonData))
            console.log("response : ", response.status)
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log("error status : ", error.response.status)
                console.log("error headers : ", error.response.headers)
                console.log("error data : ", error.response.data)
            }
        }
    }

return (
        <Box
            style={styles.pages}
        >
            <CardLogin />
            <button type="submit" onClick={dataHandlerPost}>Testing post</button>
        </Box>
    )
```

Comment: How did you define `request`? Please try wihthout `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PedroHenrique, please try `const response = await request.post("/users", jsonData)` and  to print `console.log(response, response.data)`. It should work.

Comment: I've tried without the JSON.stringy method and nothing.Well one thing that i observed is that the server is returning a 408 error timeout, and it seems the request is being made with the frorntend but the response is not returning  from the server.

Comment: Are you sure the web address is correct and reachable? Did you try hitting the endpoint with curl or an api client?

Comment: @AdamHopkins i haven't tried with curl but i've tested with api client and works just fine.The error returns normally at the api client, but with the browser it doesnt show any response in JSON, wich should be returning at the browser.Still looking for a solution.